# Identifying cache memory levels with Fortran code

Tags: performance, matrix, fortran, cpu-cache

I have a Fortran code to test the Cache memory of my computer. The code basically compares the time needed to compute the sum of 3 matrices A, B and C of size NxN. N is given as input and all the elements of the matrices are 1.0 .
The sum is made by columns and by lines to compare the Gflops (bearing in mind that in Fortran, the memory loads matrices by columns and not by lines, so: A(1,1) , A(2,1), A(3,1)...).
The for loop is repeated several times in order to compute the average time of the sum. The sum is stored in the same matrix A, so `A=A+B+C`.
The characteristics of my cache memory are:

```
hw.l3cachesize: 3145728
hw.l2cachesize: 262144
hw.l1dcachesize: 32768
hw.l1icachesize: 32768
hw.cachelinesize: 64
```

Since the elements of the matrices are of type real*8, I am expecting to find a decrease in the Gflops when going beyond the cache L1 size.
Actually I also would like to know if I should expect the change at 32 kB or 64 kB, since the L1i is 32 kB and the L1d also 32 kB.
For that I assume that the size stored in the cache in bytes is `3*N*N*8` (3 matrices and 8 bytes per element).

When I check my results I am not able to identify this change in Gflops.

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions when adding tags. Namely *"For CPU/disk/web browsing please use relevant tags (cpu-cache, diskcache,...)"*. It is quite important to get the right expert to your question. Please also show your code and your measurement results.

Comment: Please show your code, it's very difficult to answer this without seeing that

Comment: Depending on your toy test code, the compiler may be optimizing away many of the 'hard work' you are expecting it to perform.